# Lazy Load in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, lazy-loading, many-to-one

I can not make Lazy Load work on Spring.

```java
@Entity
public class Livro {

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Campo nome é obrigatorio")
    private String nome;

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyy")
    @NotNull(message = "Campo publicacao é obrigatorio")
    private Date publicacao;

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private String editora;

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private String resumo;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "livro", fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private List<Comentario> comentarios;
```

//Comentario.Java

```java
@Entity
public class Comentario {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("comentario")
    private String texto;

    private String usuario;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyy")
    private Date data;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LIVRO_ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Livro livro;
```

//LivrosRepository.java

```java
package com.curso.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.curso.domain.Livro;

public interface LivrosRepository extends JpaRepository<Livro, Long> {

}
```

//ComentariosRepository.java

```java
package com.curso.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.curso.domain.Comentario;

public interface ComentariosRepository extends JpaRepository<Comentario, Long> {



}
```

//LivrosService.java

```java
@Service
public class LivrosService {

    @Autowired
    private LivrosRepository livrosRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ComentariosRepository comentariosRepository;

   // [...]

    public List<Livro> listar() {
        return livrosRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

When I make a request to list the books, the behavior I expect is that I list all the data in books, but without the comments, since I'm using the java annotation
fetch = FetchType.LAZY, but the behavior I have is the return of all the data in the workbook.

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "nome": "Teste2",
        "publicacao": "01/01/2018",
        "editora": "Polenta",
        "comentarios": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "usuario": "tester",
                "data": "26/03/2019",
                "comentario": "Comentario 1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you returning Livro entity from your request?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Session exists within method with @Transactional. Passing entity outside Service class is a bad practise because session is being closed after leaving your `listar` method. On the other hand your entity contains lazy initialised collections (`List<Comentario> comentarios`), which cannot be pulled once session is closed.

The good practise is to map entity onto transport object and return those transport objects from service (not raw entities).

First of all you should wrap your `public List<Livro> listar()` method with `@Transactional`. Hibernate Session will be alive during execution of this method. It means you can pull lazy initialized elements within this method.
Secondly you should define `LivroDto` class with all necessary fields and map your Livro entity onto this POJO within this method then return `LivroDro` from the service.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but I did not understand, would you have an example?